# MySQL query to display the Envira Gallery Tags and their related post ID that are attached to my media library

Tags: mysql, wordpress, image-gallery

I have a query build but I keel getting the following error:
[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tt'

```
SELECT
    t.term_id,
    t. NAME,
    t.slug,
    pm.meta_value,
    tt.taxonomy,
    tr.object_id,
    tr.term_order
FROM
    wp_terms AS tt
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = tr.object_id
WHERE
    tt.taxonomy = "envira-tag"
AND pm.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
```

Comment: Well it's not unique, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your query and I did one similar recently. The error points to using "tt" too many times.

Here you are already using "tt" for a different table:

```
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
```

Looks like the alias "tt" should actually be "t".

```
FROM
    wp_terms AS t
```

When aliasing ensure you make your requests consistent with what you are referencing.